# How do I install pyTranscriber on Ubuntu 20.04 from GitHub?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, git

I am slowly wrapping my head around installing and building programs from git. The program I want is https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/, for Ubuntu 20.04.

I've tried clone-and-build instructions from https://www.howtogeek.com/428988/how-to-install-software-using-git-on-linux/, getting hung up on the `make && make` bit with this resulting output:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I then I tried downloading the `pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-installer.zip` file from https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/releases/tag/v1.5-stable and then following the instructions on https://ostoday.org/linux/how-to-install-sh-file-in-ubuntu.html – unzipping that folder, placing it in my home directory, and then getting stuck on trying to run the `install.sh` file. I get this error message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/pyTranscriber’: Permission denied
cp: target '/opt/pyTranscriber' is not a directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/pyTranscriber/*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/applications/pytranscriber.desktop': Permission denied
```

I's like to `a\` install this particular program, and `b\` understand the standard way of installing anything from GitHub/GitLab in the future. I've done this before just it's always trial by fire and I finally want to know what it is I'm doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current case you have to download the ZIP-file with installer from [releases page](https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/releases) and then install it using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/releases/download/v1.5-stable/pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-installer.zip
unzip pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-installer.zip
cd pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-installer
sudo bash install.sh
```

and then find the pyTranscriber application icon in the dash. Or launch it using `/opt/pyTranscriber/pyTranscriber` command.

---

Other way is to download portable version of application and run it with following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/releases/download/v1.5-stable/pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-portable.zip
unzip pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-portable.zip
cd pyTranscriber-v1.5-linux-portable/
./pyTranscriber
```

---

Notes: by analyzing the contents of above pyTranscriber directories you can see that they do not have any `configure` and/or `Makefile` (so `./configure` followed  by `make` command will not work), do not have any `setup.py` (so `python setup.py build` will not work either). So for this particular case you are downloading special installer packages and not the sources.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly and now I understand the anatomy of my system much better too, as well as when to use those other commands (and the benefit of actually using the Downloads directory). Thank you!

Comment: Could you possibly answer the same question, but for https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber and for 22.04.3 ? I don't see any of the same files you referenced in the current github page and I have no idea how to install and test that. Thanks!